# Get Location on SMS Receive

Tags: android

am trying to listen to a very specific SMS sent from a particular sender containing a particular keyword. For that, I have created a `BroadcastReciever` which binds to `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` through manifest.

I get a location by spinning a Service from the `OnRecieve()` method.

My question is, Will I be able to get the location even when the phone is in sleep?

I read that to get a location from GPS, screen must be turned on.

If yes, how can I resolve this ?

Comment: And can help http://aboutyusata.blogspot.in/2013/08/getting-gps-reading-in-background-in.html

Comment: @Pankaj: I do not believe this is a duplicate. My question is regarding the effect of sleep on getting location rather than getting the location itself

Comment: What you want to achieve is possible.

Comment: The second you get your SMS, create an AlarmManager which starts a Service to get your location at current time. The trick is to use RTC_WAKEUP in your AlarmManager.

Comment: Thanks Carnal. I want to know what kind of lock need to be acquired. Is there any documentation for the same ?